# Error AccessControlListNotSupported when trying to create a bucket ACL in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Recently I tried to deploy an `aws_s3_bucket_acl` resource using Terraform, and received the error:

> Error: error creating S3 bucket ACL for bucket-name: AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs │ status code: 400

I didn't see why this wouldn't create. However I checked AWS docs [[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) [2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/heads-up-amazon-s3-security-changes-are-coming-in-april-of-2023/)] and looks like they recent had an update as of April 2023 that disabled ACLs by default.

Comment: We're seeing the same error message. How did you work around the issue?

Answer (score 86):

#### The Problem

In the link you pasted, AWS changes something in the ACL (bucket S3) and it says the default value is `ObjectWriter` and to use ACL you have to set ownership to `ObjectWriter` or `BucketOwnerPreferred"` (Enable mode). If you use `BucketOwnerEnforced` (Disable), Terraform (ACL resource) will break.

Well, if the default is `ObjectWriter`, this should work to implement the ACL resource—but, with Terraform, the default value is `BucketOwnerEnforced` (The only one which doesn’t work for ACL).

### The Solution

If you see in Terraform that it is set to `aws_s3_bucket_acl` before `aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls` almost every time you apply, then, to avoid the error, you must change the order they are created: Set ownership to be created first, and put `depends_on` in the ACL resource; it will force the ownership to one value that let ACL resource be created. It will make the ownership be set to the one you want before the ACL is implemented.

### Example

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_bucket_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket-one-two.id
  acl    = "private"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.s3_bucket_acl_ownership]
}

# Resource to avoid error "AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs"
resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "s3_bucket_acl_ownership" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket-one-two.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "ObjectWriter"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

We bypassed this by adding a [`s3_bucket_ownership_controls` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_ownership_controls).

Furthermore, if you happen to use `terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws` module, simply use:

```
# S3 Bucket Ownership Controls
# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_ownership_controls
control_object_ownership = true
object_ownership         = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
```

Should work too.

Comment: If you have an already existing bucket and your Terraform still complains about not being able to create ACLs (`Error: error creating S3 bucket ACL for <bucket-name>: AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs`), you need to run `terraform apply` twice as it only recognizes the bucket ownership setting in the second run.

Comment: @chronicc. It is solved in [3.10.1 version](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3101-2023-04-28:~:text=2023%2D04%2D28\)-,Bug%20Fixes,-Fixed%20Bucket%20Policy)

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 options:

1. Add `aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls` block
2. Replace acl with bucket policy as recommended by AWS

[Bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-server-access-logging.html)

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend having a look at the Terraform registry example for an S3 bucket. It provides a good starting point for creating such resources, and the examples provided work as expected.

We were running into a similar issue, but after a while realised that it was related to our initial configuration of the S3 bucket. After using the [provided example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_acl) as a starting point, we were making good progress.